# Every torsion-free group is an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it true that every torsion-free group (i.e. a group where the only element of finite order is the identity) is abelian?

Answer (score 11):

Free groups are torsion-free but not abelian!

Comment: There are two abelian free groups. Free groups on two or more (free) generators aren't abelian.

Comment: Yup, cheers for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5):

The [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) is torsion-free but not abelian. It is the set of matrices of the form
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & a & c\\
 0 & 1 & b\\
 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}

It is torsion-free because
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & a & c\\
 0 & 1 & b\\
 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}^n
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & na & {n \choose 2}ab+nc\\
 0 & 1 & nb\\
 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It is not abelian because $(AB)_{13} \ne (BA)_{13}$.